# Test run in cypress headless gives error cy.click()

Tags: cypress

I've a test cases written in cucumber and cypress. The test case run successfully through cypress Test runner, but fails while running through headless mode using the command.

```
node_modules\.bin\cypress run --spec **/*.features

 CypressError: Timed out retrying: `cy.click()` failed because this element is not visible:
```

**Questions:**

1. what is the possible reason to have this element not visible error?
2. How can i handle the wait in headless mode?

Answer (score 0):

The fix is :

> 1. Fix all your issues displayed on the console w.r.t xpaths, sync or
>    any such.